# How to get a list of posts in Netlify CMS?

Tags: sveltekit, netlify-cms

I'd like to get a list of blog posts and the front matter to use in a site's homepage. I've looked around in the documentation of Netlify CMS but I didn't find anything that could work with this use case. I am using SvelteKit for this project

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how the posts are saved. My choice is usually as markdown files. So netlify-cms isn't really involved, except in a round-about manner. It helps to make the files with a pretty GUI but that's it really.

I look at the markdown files and load them with frontmatter to generate the HTML for the blog post pages.

Helpful resources would be [Node fs (file system)](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirsyncpath-options) `fs.readdirSync("path/to/markdown")` and `fs.readFileSync("path/to/file.md")`. There are non-sync versions also.

Here's my snippet.

```js
const postsDirectory = join(process.cwd(), 'content/posts')
export function getPostSlugs() {
    return fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory)
}
```

Comment: I saw a similar thing with `import.meta.glob` with my sveltekit/vite project. It turns out that it won't work in production when I deploy it to netlify, though, unfortunately.

Comment: @webdev03 The snippet I provided must be run in a node context. The fs package is specific to node. It will not work in the browser.